# Powershell to Script to Add Part of a Grandparent Folder to Child Item Names

Tags: powershell, windows-7, directory

At work, I maintain a large (500+) file system of my company's clients. Each client has their own folder, with subfolders for years, and account files in each year folder. On the client's folder, their is their name and a six-digit identifier number. To facilitate an upcoming audit, I was asked to attach the six digit identifier number on the grandparent folder to each of the child item account files. Is there a way to specify only a portion of the grandparent's folder to add to the child item? If so, what would be the script?

P.S. I apologize, I am very new to coding, but I'm actively trying to learn PowerShell.

Comment: I've been poking around the stackoverflow site for a solution to this code. The closest I have found was BillT's question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053364/powershell-add-grandparent-folder-name-to-file-name?rq=1>. It almost answered my question, but I would still like to know how to specifiy the portion of the folder's name to use.

Comment: If you look at this question the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351035/report-folders-which-have-a-specific-subfolder/29351595#29351595) tried to show how to get grandparent folder names. Have a look there to maybe get you started. I Welcome you to SO but know that we are here to help you with your code and not make the solution from scratch.

Comment: Actually, I'm close to figuring out a solution. If I use: 

$GrandParent = 
 $_.fullname | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf

Here, I would be affixing the full grandparent name to the child item. However, I'm not sure how to specify which part of the grandparent name to use. e.g. instead of "Bobby 123456," only "123456." The path would look like 

C:\Bobby 123456\2014\Bobby 15-5555

Comment: The desired outcome from the script would be Bobby 15-5555 123456.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to learn some [Regular Expressions](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/08/14/pshell-regular-expressions-1.aspx).

```
$GrandParent = 'C:\Bobby 123456\2014\Bobby 15-5555'
if ($GrandParent -match 'C:\\(?<Name>.*)\s(?<IDCode1>\d{6})\\(?<Year>\d{4})\\.*\s(?<IDCode2>\d{2}-\d{4})'){
    $Matches.Name
    $Matches.IDCode1
    $Matches.Year
    $Matches.IDCode2
    "{0} {1} {2}" -f $Matches.Name,$Matches.IDCode2,$Matches.IDCode1
}
```

Here is my [favorite reference for regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).